# Event-hook upon up/down-scaling or deletion of an App

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I didn't find info whether it is possible to define something like an Event-hook upon up/down-scaling or deletion of an App in the Marathon Rest API docs at https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html

What I'd like to achieve is that I'm able to backup some data from a running Docker container before be is destroyed. For example, I run a cluster of Elasticsearch nodes on Marathon, and I would like to delay the deletion of the app until the then triggered "Create snapshot to external disk resource" process is finished.

Is there currently something I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Marathon provides an [Event Bus](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/event-bus.html) covering some phases of the lifecycle. Beyond that, currently the only other option I see is to go for [Mesos Modules/Hooks](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/modules/).